# How to force Java/awt to use a specific toolkit (qt)?

Tags: java, linux, qt, awt, jamvm

I am working on an embedded Linux device that has only qt. For some reason, Java decides to use gnu.java.awt.peer.gtk.GtkToolkit. How can I force it to use gnu.java.awt.peer.qt.QtToolkit instead (or change the default behavior)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[the api](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getDefaultToolkit%28%29) suggests setting the system property awt.toolkit,

```
java -Dawt.toolkit=gnu.java.awt.peer.qt.QtToolkit my.Program
```

or

```
System.setProperty ("awt.toolkit", "gnu.java.awt.peer.qt.QtToolkit");
```

Comment: Haven't tired the first option, but the second works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can set the Default Toolkit inside of swing directly, in a compiler-friendly way.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```